# Why can't I use FTLI when $\vec{F}=\nabla f$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why can't I use Fundamental Theorem of Line Integral (FTLI) when $\vec{F}=\nabla f$?

And what's an easy way to check if an equation is smooth(differentiable)?

Comment: what is FTLI as used here?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Line Integral

Answer (score 1):

This is a completely vague question. Of course, the FTLI applies precisely to vector fields that are gradients: $$\int_C \nabla f\cdot d\vec r = f(B)-f(A)\,,$$ where $C$ is a path from $A$ to $B$.